# Delphi XE7 smart pointers

Tags: delphi, smart-pointers, delphi-xe7

I am new to Delphi with a C++ background and trying to figure out how smart pointers can be implemented. I came across the following post, which I am trying to use as my own starting point: [Delphi - smart pointers and generics TList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28968208/delphi-smart-pointers-and-generics-tlist)

However I can't compile the previous code using Delphi XE7 (compiler errors are shown as comments in code). Also I would greatly appreciate it if someone actually explained the code's logic (initially I wanted to use the class as a drop in utility class but now I would like to understand what is actually happening). I vaguely understand that because the smart pointer implementation is inheriting from TInterfacedObject, it is reference counted but anything beyond that makes no sense to me :)

```
unit SmartPointer;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, System.Generics.Collections;

type
  ISmartPointer<T> = reference to function: T;

  // complains ISmartPointer<T> expecting an interface type
  TSmartPointer<T: class, constructor> = class(TInterfacedObject,ISmartPointer<T>)
  private
    FValue: T;
  public
    constructor Create; overload;
    constructor Create(AValue: T); overload;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Invoke: T;
  end;

implementation

{ TSmartPointer<T> }

constructor TSmartPointer<T>.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FValue := T.Create;
end;

// complains: overload procedure TSmartPointer.Create must be marked with the overload directive
constructor TSmartPointer<T>.Create(AValue: T);
begin
  inherited Create;
  if AValue = nil then
    FValue := T.Create
  else
    FValue := AValue;
end;

destructor TSmartPointer<T>.Destroy;
begin
  FValue.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TSmartPointer<T>.Invoke: T;
begin
  Result := FValue;
end;

end.
```

Tried to use the previous smart pointer with following test code which resulted in a compiler error…what am I missing?

```
program TestSmartPointer;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, SmartPointer;

type
TPerson = class
  private
    _name : string;
    _age : integer;
  public

    property Name: string read _name write _name;
    property Age: integer read _age write _age;
  end;

var
  pperson : TSmartPointer<TPerson>;

begin
  try
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
    pperson := TSmartPointer<TPerson>.Create();
    // error on next line: undeclared Identifier: Name
    pperson.Name := 'John Doe';
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Try Stefan Gliencke's blog post: http://delphisorcery.blogspot.be/2015/01/smart-pointers-in-delphi.html

Comment: Yes saw that and even digged in the Spring4d implementation. What I would like is to understand what is happening in the previous code.

Comment: My advice is not to use smart pointers. They are an idiom that doesn't fit in the language.

Comment: Why? Perhaps I am missing something but I see lots of Delphi code with Try Except Finally blocks where the Finally block is used to release memory. I really think the whole approach is completely error prone (and indeed it is because the current code base is littered with memory leaks). Smart pointers would just make the whole thing a lot less error-prone

Comment: If smart pointers are such a great fit, why aren't we all using them? Waiting until the procedure ends before objects are destroyed in an unpredictable order has its own problems. Try/finally is not hard. My large app has no smart pointers, and no leaks. Delphi smart pointers can never be the same as C++ RAII. Program into the language. Don't fight against it.

Comment: Regarding order, in C++ RAII you know that all resources are cleaned up when the object goes out of scope, in reverse order of acquisition. You've no idea whatsoever what order things happen with these Delphi "smart" pointers. All you know is that it happens when the procedure returns. You can't have scopes smaller than a procedure. And you can't control the order. If it was a good idea then everyone would be doing it.

Comment: Smart pointers are a dead end. Handling life time of objects with try/finally is simple and predictable. And should you ever make a mistake, FastMM helps you find the leak in no time. The RTL has many problems, but memory leaks from manual handling of objects are not the big issue here. (The mobile ARC model is another ballgame, and in its current state a place for lots of errors and confusion).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You can have predictable order and scope smaller than procedure. All you have to do is to nil smart pointer and it will trigger destructor at that point (of course, if you don't have more than one reference to the smart pointer instance).

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with using smart pointers in Delphi. There is nothing about them that would not fit the Delphi language. If reference counted object instances fit, then smart pointers fit too.

Comment: I don't have XE7, so I cannot test it there, but above code works fine in XE4.

Comment: I don't quite see what is wrong with smart pointers in Delphi. I wrote one of the first implementations of them, back then in the early days of the JCL. I think they are a great idiom and they will, AFAICT, be released in the reverse order as well. Delphi's smart pointers are actually better than most RAII implementations, because refcounting means they can be passed around (and returned from a function) and are not limited to the current scope.

Comment: @Rudy That's just plain wrong. You can't predict the order they will be released in.

Comment: @Dalija You need try finally blocks to enforce a specific order. At which point you are back where you started with a boat load of extra bloat.

Comment: @Dalija And then of course you have the hidden implicit finally blocks that the compiler emits too.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan First, you have to care about releasing order in the first place, second you can achieve it by nilling the pointers. The only time that will not work is if any of the code throws exception, and if you do care about order in that case single try..finally would do, instead of multiple ones.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sometimes code readability comes before performance, and smart pointers can make code more readable.

Comment: @Dalija If you don't care about the order all this is moot. If you do care then you need finally blocks. Readability is very important. To the well versed, finally blocks can be quite readable. I've yet to see any code where Delphi smart pointers leads to a significant benefit when compared to explicit resource management.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Single try..finally block is much more readable than nested ones, and with smart pointers (if you care about order) you only need one.

Comment: @Dalija single finally is possible either way, if you wish

Comment: @DavidHeffernan with possibility that you forget to preinitialize some of the object references to nil. And you can catch that only if code blows, so if order is important you are much safer with smart pointers than with anything else.

Comment: @Dalija That never happens once you've learnt the pattern though. What I see here is a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: @ DavidHefferman I disagree. The reason why I started looking at smart pointers in the first place is because I am facing code with memory leaks…the developers in question are strong advocates of the try..finally paradigm but in practice you can easily forget to free a variable when you have lots of variables.

Comment: Only if you aren't very good. And in that case you'll make other mistakes. No amount of tooling can turn a poor programmer into a good programmer. Anyway, I've expressed my point of view, as a Delphi developer with 20 years experience. Obviously you are free to choose whatever path you desire.

Comment: AFAIK, each interface gets its own try-finally block. These are of course nested properly.

Comment: And try-finally is not necessarily **more** readable. It clutters the routine, especially if nested, while smart pointers don't.

Comment: @David: it may sound arrogant, but I assume that most programmers are average, and only a few are very good. And, beside a few obvious cases perhaps, I don't know how to tell them apart. FWIW, I have more than 30 years of programming experience. <g>

Comment: @Rudy Still, you appear unaware that intf finalization order is not specified. An average programmer can handle try/finally. I'd say that try/foinally was easier to master than Delphi smart pointers because it is explicit and visible. Your 30 years of experience is valuable if you have built and/or maintained a >100kloc system exclusively using delphi smart pointers. When I hear from anyone that has done so, I'm interested. Until even one such case can be found, DSP remains a quaint curiosity.

Comment: @Rudy Again I ask the following question. If DSP is such a great idea, where are all the projects making extensive use of them?

Comment: Like people from other languages, Delphi programmers have their habits. That is why smart pointers have never become popular. But popularity is not a sign of quality, right?

Comment: I find smart pointers extremely easy to master. Fact is that you **can't forget** to `Free` something that is under the guard of a smart pointer. Every `try-finally-end` is something that must be coded manually, and that violates DRY, IMO. So I wonder why people actually think Delphi smart pointers are a bad idea. The compiler is much better at taking care of such things than a human programmer is. It is like the discussion of shift gear vs. automatic. I prefer automatic, even though I like a "sportive" way of driving.

Comment: @Rudy You can master try/finally easily as well. In the simple cases, either way is easy to do. It's the more complex cases that are interesting. And despite your self-professed ability to master dsp, you got it wrong regarding order of finalization.

Comment: There's also another difference between C++ and Delphi which makes smart pointers valuable in C++ but far less useful in Delphi. An exception thrown in a C++ constructor won't invoke the destructor, while Delphi calls the destructor automatically. Thereby while Delphi can clean up properly a failed object construction (as long as you properly code the destructor to clean a partially constructed instance), C++ can't, so it has to rely on something else.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan from a software engineering basis is there something inherently wrong about using smart pointers? Ie is the above implementation broken and might leak memory? I understand your argument about not having precise control on object lifecyle and order of destruction. You don't have that control in garbage collected languages either. It sounds that the whole discussion evolves around personal habits. Same thing for interfaces, I think they are great for building decoupled software. They are also ref-counted which neatly takes care of memory management...

Comment: FWIW, for me DSP is Digital Signal Processing. I assume you mean Delphi Smart Pointers? Try-finally-end is something that can be done wrong, and it is easy to forget something. It is against DRY. If I'm wrong WRT order of finalization, show me. <g>

Comment: @Big Smart pointers in Delphi are quite different from smart pointers in C++. Here were are talking about the utility of Delphi smart pointers. Yes you can use them. Yes they do work. Are they useful? I don't think so. I don't perceive them to give a significant benefit over manual allocation. That's my opinion. So yes, your reading of my comments is accurate. This comes down to opinion.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OK this was an honest question. The reason I wondered about smart pointers in Delphi is because as a developer with C++ experience I see my Delphi colleagues dealing with memory leaks the size of a busted oil tanker on the shores of Bretagne. I naively asked one of them why they were not using smart pointers and the guy looked at me with the same expression Bill Murray had in "Lost in Translation" in the Suntory whiskey scene...and answered "smart what...what are you talking about?"  And yes these guys are strong followers of try...finally {release here}

Comment: @DavidHeffernan And then those same colleagues are in total awe in front of FastMM because it can detect a memory leak so well (after having shipped a leaking tanker to the client)...but to me as a C++ developer it's like reacting to a problen ex-post instead of ex-ante and being in awe in front of the pain-alleviating benefits of aspirin after having shot yourself in the foot with a gun with the security off

Comment: Again, I'd suggest think twice before you mix a C++ idiom with Delphi idioms. If you end up with code with multiple lifetime management techniques that could be even more confusing. I'd say your real problem is that the existing devs are poor. Step 1 is to improve their skills. I'd go that by fixing the project using the current design. Plug all the leaks. FastMM will help. Once you've brought the existing devs up to scratch, and once you are more experienced with Delphi, you'll be better placed to judge whether or not to make sweeping architectural changes to the code base.

Comment: Also, thanks for the interesting discussion. I've found it quite thought provoking.

Comment: @david: i think you're overreacting. There is nothing wrong with smart pointers in Delphi, except that they are not really well known. IMO, they beat try-finally by lebgths, but they are, ubfirtunately, not part of the RTL, which is why they have never become very popular.

Comment: Hmmm... Typing a commentbon an iPad has its disadvantages

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Forgetting cleanup at finally block isn't a sign of "bad programmer". You can have an excellent programmer who layers his code with great abstraction techniques, chooses adequate data structures but still forgets a line of code in the finally block once or twice a year. 

I think it boils down to the fact that delphi has a try..finally construct and you're right, introducing smart pointers would cause confusion at the language level. Projects would have to start without try..finally and you would have to wrap everything in order to get consistency and not having RAII is a pain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to declare your reference variable as `ISmartPointer<TPerson>`:

```
var
  pperson : ISmartPointer<TPerson>;
```

The following code would also compile, but it would not automatically release memory in this case, because when you store a reference-counted object instance into a object reference you mess up its reference-counting mechanism. Depending on the code, it can result in memory leaks or premature destruction of the underlying object instance.

```
var
  pperson : TSmartPointer<TPerson>;

begin
  pperson := TSmartPointer<TPerson>.Create();
  pperson.Invoke.Name := 'John Doe';
```

Finally the following code illustrates the correct smart pointer usage:

```
var
  pperson : ISmartPointer<TPerson>;   // note pperson is ISmartPointer<TPerson>

begin
  pperson := TSmartPointer<TPerson>.Create();
  pperson.Name := 'John Doe';
```

**Some interface basics**

An interface defines a contract - functionality that the class implementing the interface must have, without providing a specific implementation. The `IFoo` interface declaration means when you have reference to `IFoo`, you can call `Foo` method on that reference, but that is all you can.

```
IFoo = interface
  procedure Foo;
end;
```

When a class implements an interface, it must implement all methods from that interface. Method `Foo` from `IFoo` will map to method `Foo` from `TFoo`
or `TOtherFoo`. Implementation of specific interfaces can be different in different classes.

```
TFoo = class(TInterfacedObject, IFoo)
public
  procedure Foo;
  procedure Bar;
end;

TOtherFoo = class(TInterfacedObject, IFoo)
public
  procedure Foo;
end;

procedure TFoo.Bar;
begin
  writeln('Bar');
end;

procedure TFoo.Foo;
begin
  writeln('Foo');
end;

procedure TOtherFoo.Foo;
begin
  writeln('Other Foo');
end;

var
  foo: IFoo;
  f: TFoo;

  foo := TFoo.Create;
  foo.Foo; // Output -> Foo

  // Compiler error -> foo is interface reference and only knows Foo from TFoo
  foo.Bar;

  foo := TOtherFoo.Create;
  foo.Foo; // Output -> Other Foo

  // Mixing object reference with reference counted object instance -> memory leaks
  f := TFoo.Create;
  foo.Foo; // output -> Foo
  foo.Bar; // f is TFoo object reference, and it knows everything from TFoo
```

**How a smart pointer actually works**

`ISmartPointer<T>` is declared as anonymous function.

```
ISmartPointer<T> = reference to function: T;
```

Above declaration is equivalent of interface with `Invoke` function

```
ISmartPointer<T> = interface
  function Invoke: T;
end;
```

The difference between the two (the one we are interested here) is that with anonymous function/methods you don't have to explicitly call `Invoke`; the compiler will do that for you.

Since `ISmartPointer<T>` is an anonymous function, which is actually an interface in declaration of `TSmartPointer<T>` class, `Invoke` method will be mapped to `ISmartPointer<T>`.

```
  TSmartPointer<T: class, constructor> = class(TInterfacedObject, ISmartPointer<T>)
  private
    FValue: T;
  public
    constructor Create; overload;
    constructor Create(AValue: T); overload;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Invoke: T;
  end;

var
  pperson : ISmartPointer<TPerson>;
```

So when you write `pperson.Name` behind the curtains that translates to a `pperson.Invoke` function call which returns a `TPerson` instance from `FValue` and `TPerson` has the `Name` property that the compiler can recognize.

Since `TSmartPointer<T>` is a reference-counted class, when you use `ISmartPointer<T>` references, the underlying `TSmartPointer<T>` object instance, together with the `T` instance it contains in `FValue` will be automatically released when the `ISmartPointer<T>` reference goes out of scope, or you set it to `nil` in code.