# Delphi avoid try finally block

Tags: delphi

I have learnt that in Delphi I have to use `try .. finally` to free the allocated object on the heap. In java I never do this because it's not my job but that's something that the garbage collector does. Also delphi hasn't ref count on windows and so I need to use the try finally. Is there an alternative?

Do I have to use interface or a particular class to avoid the guard? like

```
var a: ttest;
begin
 a := ttest.create;
 //do stuff
end;
```

Comment: Yo can use smart pointers (C++ concept) or IMultiSafeGuard (from JCL). Just google them and you'll find everything you need

Comment: It's a mistake to try to force this style of coding into a language that doesn't really want it. You end up with very artifical constructs. Using try/finally is not difficult.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ive seen that marco cantu made an implementation of smart pointers. He can do what I need and they're easy to use. var
sl: TStringList;
smartP: TSmartPointer<TStringList>;
begin
sl := TStringList.Create;
smartP.Create (sl);
end;

Comment: It's pointless. The resulting code is confusing and opaque. And you still have to deal with library code that isn't written that way so it's yet another pattern to follow. If you want to code in Java, code in Java.

Comment: @PaulL If I inherited a codebase filled with that nonsense I would certainly be overcome with an urge to do physical harm to the original programmer.  In the context of programming it would be like reading code that was written in a terrible accent that you have to fight to understand.  It's much better to write code the way the language is designed to be used.

Comment: @PaulL that involves generics, class operators, interfaces and conversion between types. I won't say that it's very easy...

Comment: @AlbertoMiola if it's not easy then why you suggested it?

Comment: @PaulL well your question is "avoid try finally blocks" and with smart pointers/ IMultiSafeGuard you can avoid the try finally block. No argue on this but their implementation/usage is another story; mine was just a comment so that you can have an idea of what you can get into.

Comment: Probably it's me, but it seems here that people cannot adapt to changes and there is no flexibility ;)

Comment: @PaulL As tool users, it is us who have to adapt.  If you're used to a screwdriver and you're given a spanner you have to learn how to use the new tool, not to insist that a spanner should work like a screwdriver.  Now you've got the bolt held with the spanner handle stuck upright and you're trying to turn the thing with a pair of pliers and complaining that a screwdriver simply "worked" better... because you refused to adapt to the normal way of using a new tool.

Comment: The person here unwilling to adapt is none other than yourself. Program into the language. Don't try to swim upstream. We have all explored writing code the way you suggest, and we know how it ends up. Anyway, if you are desperate for a smart pointer, go ahead. It's your choice.

Comment: And then you will have an Access Violation or a memory leak, of which the debugger will warn you or a tool like FastMM. Furthermore this all depends on the coding style you prefer. No accounting for taste. In my opinion, smart  pointers only tend to confuse. Learn the language first, and it's intricacies, before you start working over the existing methods of disposing objects and memory management. I find a certain elegance in knowing when an object goes out of scope, and that I clean it up. It helps me understand the lifetime of my code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan FWIW, I stand by the dentist :) SmartPointer is just the tool, and it can be abused just like any other, but it has its place and can increase safety and readability of the code, preventing accidental mistakes.Good SmartPointer implementations can give you compiler safety.

Comment: @dalija The problem is yet another pattern to follow. More and more different ways to achieve the same thing just creates confusion. That's why we like patterns and uniformity. It allows us to concentrate on that which matters. Delphi's function level scoping means you have no control over when the objects are destroyed, as you do in C++. That one difference alone is huge. And for all of this, what is the gain from the additional complexity of having two methods to do the same thing? Is the gain significant? I say no. I say we are solving a problem that does not exist.

Comment: @David: the problem does exist. I assume not for you, and not for me either, but deciding when and how to free an object seems to be a big problem for many. Anything that relieves them from that burden can be beneficial to them, be it something like RAII (e.g. guard interfaces) or, say ARC. And the argument "we have always done it this way" is not a very good one either.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Problem is not in another pattern to follow. Problem is that there is no universal SmartPointer implementation provided by RTL that can be used consistently and the even greater problem is in inexperienced developer coming from other language that might use SmartPointer in inappropriate places. Other than that there is nothing wrong with using SmartPointer or any other automatic memory management available.

Comment: @Rudy There is no problem. Manual memory management is trivial. Programmers that aren't skilled enough to get it right aren't skilled enough to write good programs. Designing for these programmers is senseless. Large nested try blocks? That's a symptom of a deeper malaise.

Comment: I agree with @DavidHeffernan here, learn what your code is doing in terms of memory management. Abstracting the problem away because people can't handle it is a symptom of a different problem.

Comment: @David: for many, manual memory management (and especially lifetime management) is far from trivial. For those people, it is a (big) problem. I agree with you that manual lifetime management is trivial if you follow certain principles. But even then, it is pretty convenient not having to *care* about it, even if it is easy.

Comment: @rudy My point is that any programmer that can't manage try finally is not going to succeed. Why spoil things for the rest of us, as happened with the introduction of ARC.

Comment: I have to agree with David on this one. As a programmer in both Delphi and c# the thing I hate most in c# is the garbage collection. I really wish it was never invented because it does not stops all memory leaks and I find try...finally very elegant, readable, easy and logic

Comment: @David Can you please tone down the personal nature of the attacks against Rudy? This isn't the first post where I've seen those, and they just aren't necessary. You can make the argument from your own real-world experience without explicitly belittling others.

Comment: And more generally, to everyone: if you want to share a well-reasoned, thought-out opinion on why doing what the asker wants to do is a bad idea, then post it as an answer to the question: "Don't do this because x. Do y instead". Comments are not for extended discussion, precisely because the information gets lost in the noise. Thanks!

Comment: @Cody "Personally, although I am a long time Delphi programmer" was the original comment. I'm making the point that hobbyist programming doesn't give the same range of experience as long term maintenance programming. And the bio here (https://stackoverflow.com/users/95954/rudy-velthuis) does not contradict anything I said.

Comment: @Rudy You still have to remember to use the smart pointers. So there's no advantage there. With either option you have to remember something. Option 1: remember to destroy the object. Option 2: remember to wrap it in a smart pointer. No difference. If you can do one of the above you can do both. And if you opt for smart pointers there are the downsides. Lack of consistency between different libraries. Lack of control of destruction. Reference counting scope being the function rather than the block. Of course I can see the attraction of smart pointers, but in my view the cons outweigh the pros.

Comment: Anyway, this is, as usual pointless waffle from us all. We've made our points which we have made so many times before. @Cody would be best just to remove all the comments!

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Fine. So you agree that there's no more chance of you forgetting to do what is necessary to ensure correct lfetime management with either option.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis That's not how accurate though. The `Free` may end up far away, but it doesn't start that way. When you write `obj := TMyObject.Create` you always deal with the destruction at that time. Then you fill in the block between the try and finally. Nested try is a symptom of a bigger problem. And then there are the smart pointer drawbacks that I listed earlier. They look like a good idea, but in practice the end result is code that is far from the typical idioms, for no clear gains.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I'm not interested in discussions about mistakes made by incompetent programmers. You can't design your language for that. The point about the associated `Free` being located far from the constructor is more valid. But the same criticism would apply equally to the line of code immediately before the `finally`. Any reading, reviewing, etc. would have to read that far anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use interfaces for some things, but fundamentally there is no getting around the fact that Delphi simply does not implement garbage collection or reference counting for regular objects in the legacy desktop compilers for Windows and OSX (it does use reference counting in the NextGen compilers for Android, iOS, and Linux***).

It is not practical to use interfaces for everything, so you simply have to get used to cleaning up after yourself.  If you create an object, free it when you are done using it.

Now, there are all kinds of clever patterns you can come up with to tidy up, or work around, having to use a simple `try/finally` block, but this ends up being a lot of work and you end up producing bulky, awkward code that does not flow with the style of the language.  Invariably, you will also be using third party libraries, components, etc, and all of these will generally be written in a style common to most Delphi code.

To brutishly force an artificial memory management pattern on top of this will be far more work than simply doing it the "Delphi way", and will produce code that is difficult for other programmers to understand and work with.  Just don't do it.

Smart pointers are one way to automate lifetime management. A good example implementation can be found here:

[Delphi - smart pointers and generics TList](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28968920/327083)

But this becomes a difficult pattern to generalize, particularly for objects with constructors taking a variety of parameter lists.  An interface or a smart pointer implementation is usually a tool created to solve a specific type of problem.  They aren't applied as a broad-brush solution to automatic memory management, and trying to shoehorn them into this role will make for a very difficult time indeed.

---

*** Since the time of this answer's writing, even Embarcadero [have abandoned object ARC](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2018-october-Delphi-ARC-directions.html) in the new compilers for similar reasons.